# Is there a shortcut to go to the beginning/end of a file in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I often need to get quickly to the very beginning or very end of a file in the IntelliJ editor. Is there a shortcut key or button that allows me to do this quickly?

I am running on Windows, if that matters.

Answer (score 31):

Beginning of File: <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

End of File: <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

---

**Note**: This answer was posted prior to `windows` specificity. Leaving it here to include MacOS alternative.

Comment: And how could you change this shortcut?  In other words, what should I search for in preferences->keymap?

Comment: @ScottBiggs That's described in the answer below: search for "move caret to page"

Comment: AKA "Move Caret to Text End" is the setting OP is looking for. Poorly named, IMO, since that reads as "end of line" or something along those lines. "Page Bottom" or "File Bottom" would be less confusing, and "Page Bottom" should be replaced with "Window Bottom" or "View Bottom". Anyways...

Answer (score 11):

On Windows, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to go to the beginning and end of a file respectively.

Comment: Page up, Page down is too slow for a little big file. That should immediately jump to the beginning or end of the file.

Comment: Cmd+Home and Cmd+End work on my Mac (using an extended external keyboard which has Home and End keys).

Answer (score 5):

The action is called **Move caret to Page Top/Bottom**, default shortcuts would depend on the OS/Keymap and can be checked here:

[image: top]

On Windows these are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

Comment: This seems to move the caret to the top/bottom of the visible page, not the top/bottom of the file.  While it could be useful at times, it's not what the OP asked for.  (I'm using Android Studio 3.4.2)

Comment: Proper action name is `Move caret to text end`

Answer (score 4):

To find what keyboard strokes are already defined for this, go to Preferences->Keymap and search for `text start` for jumping to the beginning of the file and `text end` for jumping to the end of the file.  You'll get something that looks like this:

[image]

The right column tells you what keystrokes have been mapped to these functions.  Feel free to change them to something that you find more intuitive by double clicking on the right column and following the instructions on the pop-ups.

Answer (score 4):

On a Mac, these following keys:

- to start of the file:

> option + command + [

- to end of the file:

> option + command + ]

Comment: For me: this goes to the end of whatever scope I'm in (e.g., end of method, end of json object), not to the end of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Under `preferences` -> `Keymap`, a shortcut for `Scroll to Bottom`and `Scroll to Top` can be set.

By default, they are not assigned.

Comment: There ya go! $$

Answer (score 1):

By default in windows the shortcut is

> ctrl+end

You can customize the shortcut. To use only `end` button as shortcut go to Settings -> Keymap -> Editor action -> move caret to text end
Right click on `move caret to text end` and update shortcut to `end`

Answer (score 0):

After spending minutes to search on the web, i don't find the answer for just using `cmd` + `up` or `down`. If you are the same, as a quick workaround, you can `cmd` + `a` to select all text and press `up` or `down` to move it.